# How can i make this app recognize multiple images

Tags: swift, xcode, arkit

I have made an app that recognize's a piece of art/drawing/paper etc using ARKit. When it recognize's the images it switches to another View Controller and tells you about it. It can recognize one piece of art. The question is how can i have the app recognize multiple drawings. Here is the code.
AR View Controller:

```html
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import ARKit
import AVFoundation

struct ImageInformation {
    let name: String
    let description: String
    let image: UIImage
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, ARSKViewDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSKView!
    @IBAction func options(){
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Options", message: "Select one of the options below to continue.", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Enable Flashlight", style: .default, handler: { action in
            //Enable Flashlight function
            func toggleTorch(on: Bool) {
                guard let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.video),
                        device.hasTorch
                    else { return }

                    do {
                        try device.lockForConfiguration()
                        device.torchMode = on ? .on : .off
                        device.unlockForConfiguration()
                    } catch {
                        //Torch can not be used.
                        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Flashlight Error", message: "We are unable to activate the flashlight. This could be because the flashlight is being used by another app", preferredStyle: .alert)

                        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dissmis", style: .default, handler: nil))
                        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Restart App", style: .destructive, handler: { action in
                            fatalError("The flashlight could not be used and user restarted app.")
                        }))

                        self.present(alert, animated: true)
                    }
                }
                toggleTorch(on: true)
        

        }))
        //Continue working on this function when you get back!!!
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Disable Flashlight", style: .default, handler: { action in
            //Enable flashlight function here
            func toggleTorch(off: Bool) {
                guard let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.video),
                        device.hasTorch
                    else { return }

                    do {
                        try device.lockForConfiguration()
                        device.torchMode = off ? .on : .off
                        device.unlockForConfiguration()
                    } catch {
                        //Torch can not be used.
                        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Flashlight Error", message: "We are unable to activate the flashlight. This could be because the flashlight is being used by another app", preferredStyle: .alert)

                        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dissmis", style: .default, handler: nil))
                        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Restart App", style: .destructive, handler: { action in
                            fatalError("The flashlight could not be used and user restarted app.")
                        }))

                        self.present(alert, animated: true)
                    }
                }
            toggleTorch(off: false)
        }))
        
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Clear Recently Visited Artworks", style: .destructive, handler: { action in
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let secondViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "action_done")
            self.present(secondViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
        }))
        
        
        
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        
        
        self.present(alert, animated: true)
    }
    
 
    
    var selectedImage : ImageInformation?
    
    let images = ["flower" : ImageInformation(name: "Flower Drawing", description: "This is a drawing of a flower and was made by the developer of this app. It was intended to be a thank you card for a teacher on Teacher appreciation day. The Teacher enjoyed the project.", image: UIImage(named: "flower")!)]
    
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        
        
        
        sceneView.delegate = self
        sceneView.showsFPS = false
        sceneView.showsNodeCount = false
        
        if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "Scene") {
            sceneView.presentScene(scene)
        }
        
        guard let referenceImages = ARReferenceImage.referenceImages(inGroupNamed: "AR Resources", bundle: nil) else {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Resources not Found", message: "The files needed for this application to work propely can not be found. What would you like to do about this?", preferredStyle: .alert)

            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Continue Anyway", style: .default, handler: nil))
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Restart App", style: .default, handler: { action in
                fatalError("The Recources could not be found on the users device.")
            }))

            self.present(alert, animated: true)
            return
        }
        
        let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
        configuration.detectionImages = referenceImages
        
        sceneView.session.run(configuration, options: [.resetTracking, .removeExistingAnchors])
    }
    
    
    // MARK: - ARSKViewDelegate
    func view(_ view: ARSKView, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SKNode? {
        
        if let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor,
            let referenceImageName = imageAnchor.referenceImage.name,
            let scannedImage =  self.images[referenceImageName] {
            
            self.selectedImage = scannedImage
            
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "switch", sender: self)
            
            
            return imageSeenMarker()
        }
        
        return nil
    }
    
    private func imageSeenMarker() -> SKLabelNode {
        let labelNode = SKLabelNode(text: "✅")
        labelNode.horizontalAlignmentMode = .center
        labelNode.verticalAlignmentMode = .center
        
        return labelNode
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "switch"{
            if let imageInformationVC = segue.destination as? ImageInformationViewController,
                let actualSelectedImage = selectedImage {
                imageInformationVC.imageInformation = actualSelectedImage
            }
}
}
}
```

Information View Controller:

```html
import Foundation
import UIKit

class ImageInformationViewController : UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var descriptionText: UILabel!
    
    var imageInformation : ImageInformation?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        if let actualImageInformation = imageInformation {
            self.nameLabel.text = actualImageInformation.name
            self.imageView.image = actualImageInformation.image
            self.descriptionText.text = actualImageInformation.description
        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func dismissView(_ sender: Any) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

How Can i do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function [`referenceImages(inGroup:bundle:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arreferenceimage/2948910-referenceimages) loads all reference images from your assets. Just put multiple images into your AR Resource Group in your Assets and assign a unique name for all of them.